# specify return fields for all find calls on model in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, model

I can't believe I don't remember how to do this, but how do I specify in my model the default fields that are returned with the `find()` methods? I can't find on google how to do this, or at least I don't know the wording to search for.

Comment: 2.2.4 latest stable i believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will most likely need to do, is to check if the `fields` key exists in a `beforeFind()` method in your model.

If the `fields` key is not set, you can set it to $this->fields in your native models, and create the `beforeFind()` in your AppModel, then you can instruct that method to use the `$this->fields` array from your models.

**UPDATE**

// AppModel.php

```
parent function beforeFind($queryData = array()) {
    if (empty($queryData['fields']) && !empty($this->fields)) {
        $queryData['fields'] = $this->fields;
    }
    return $queryData;
}
```

// And in your Model:

```
public $fields = array(
    'Alert.id'
);
```

This will check for existence of a `fields` array, and will then check for existence of a `$this->fields` property. If it does exist, it will apply it to the query data and return that modified query data to the `beforeFind()` - this will change your find.

Adjust it to fit your needs, and good luck!

Comment: That's for model associations

Comment: d'oh! I misunderstood the question. Hang on - You may need to declare this in the `beforeFind()` method of your model.